# Calculation filtered sets in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table invoving sort of 3 sets and I'm going to calculate the count of sets in whcich there is no (TaskId = 4), How can I achieve that?

```
SetId     TaskId

1           0
1           1
1           4

2           0
2           2
2           3

3           0
3           2
3           4
```

Comment: edit the question add sample output please

Comment: You can simply add where in the query like "where TaskId != 4". Or could you elaborate your question?

Comment: In that case it returns 7 while I want it to return 1, I need to know the number of sets not rows

Comment: count the number of `4's` in each `SetId` and filter the `SetId's` which is having count more than `1`. This can be done in so many ways...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SetId
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY SetId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TaskId = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

The basic idea here is to scan each `SetId` group of records and count the number of times which a `TaskId` value of 4 occurs.  The `HAVING` clause retains only groups for which the 4 value never occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression to check whether the `TaskId` value is 4. And use `SUM` function with grouping `SetId`.

**Query**

```
select [SetId], 
SUM(case [TaskId] when 4 then 0 else 1 end) as [sum]
from [your_table_name]
group by [SetId];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t1
WHERE t1.SetId NOT IN (SELECT t2.SetId FROM mytable t2 WHERE t2.TaskId = 4)
```

(select the full sets that have no TaskId=4)

or

```
SELECT distinct SetId
FROM mytable t1
WHERE t1.SetId NOT IN (SELECT t2.SetId FROM mytable t2 WHERE t2.TaskId = 4)
```

(select just the SetIds that have no TaskId=4)